# Which objective is optimized Intra-Cluster sum of distances or MSE?

Tags: optimization, cluster-analysis

In the cluster analysis papers using meta-heuristic algorithms, many has optimized Mean-Squared Quantization Error (MSE). For example in 
[[1]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568494609000854) and [[2]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2210650212000235) .

I have a confusion with the results. They have told that they have used the MSE as the objective function. But they have reported the result values in intra-cluster sum of Euclidean distances.

K-Means minimizes Within-Cluster Sum of Squares (WCSS) (from wiki) [[3]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). I could not find what is the difference between WCSS and MSE, when Euclidean distance is used in the case of the difference metric when calculating MSE.

In the case of K-Means the WCSS is minimized, and if we use the same MSE function with the meta-heuristics algorithms they will also minimize it. In this case how the sum of Euclidean distances for the K-Means and the other vary?

I can reproduce the results shown in the papers if I optimize the intra-cluster sum of Euclidean distances.

I think I am doing something wrong here. Can anyone help me with this.

**Main question**: What objectives did the referenced papers [[1]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568494609000854) and [[2]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2210650212000235) optimize, and which function's values are shown in the table?

Answer (score 1):

K-means optimizes the (sum of within-cluster-) **sum of squares** aka variance aka sum of squared Euclidean distances.

This is easy to see if you study the convergence proof.

I can't study the two papers you referenced. They're with crappy Elsevier and paywalled, and I'm not going to pay $36+$32 to answer your question.

Update: I managed to get a free copy of one of them. They call it "MSE, mean-square quantization error", but their *equation* is the usual within-cluster-sum-of-squares, *no mean involved*; with a shady self-citation attached to this statement, and half of the references being self-citations... it seems like it's more this author that likes to call it different than everybody else. Looks  bit like "reinventing the wheel with a different name" to me. I'd carefully double-check their results. I'm not saying they are false, I havn't checked in more detail. But the "mean-square error" doesn't involve a mean for sure; it's the sum of squared errors.

Update: if "intra-cluster sum" means sum of pairwise distances of any two objects, consider the following:

Without loss of generality, move the data such that the mean is 0. (Translation doesn't change Euclidean or squared Euclidean distances).

```
sum_x sum_y sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2
= sum_x sum_y [ sum_i (x_i)^2 + sum_i (y_i)^2 - 2 sum_i (x_i*y_i) ]
= n * sum_x sum_i (x_i)^2 + n * sum_y sum_i (y_i)
  - 2 * sum_i [sum_x x_i * sum_y y_i]
```

The first two summands are the same. So we have `2n` times the WCSS. 
But since `mu_i = 0`, `sum_x x_i = sum_y y_i = 0`, and the third term disappears.

If I didn't screw up this computation, then the *mean, asymmetric* pairwise squared Euclidean distance within a cluster *is* the same as WCSS.

Comment: This is just two examples of many more papers who use the sum of square distances within cluster. The citations seemed problematic to me too.
Is there any problem in optimizing the intra cluster sum of euclidean distances ? My study tells, if I am not making a mistake, although they have told to optimize MSE, but they have optimized the intra cluster sum of euclidean distances.

Comment: The least-distance nearest cluster is always also the least-squared-distance nearest cluster. So taking the square root usually doesn't harm much. Assuming that "intra cluster" for you is object-to-center, not pairwise-distances.

Comment: Also I believe there is an subtle equality there to the latter case.

Comment: Intra cluster for me here is the sum of the distances of each point from its nearest centroid. But there papers and others were able to confuse me enough on what is actually optimized. I think better to show cluster validity using other metric once I optimize the intra cluster sum of euclidean distances.

Comment: Please see the updated answer; on the equality of pairwise squared Euclidean distances, and sum of squared deviations from the mean.

Comment: I have gone through some study and concluded that most probably they have optimized sum of intra cluster distances, and also reported the sum of intra cluster distances, instead of first optimizing sum of squared intra cluster distances and then reporting sum of intra cluster distances.

(Pardon the very confusing lines above :D)